# Sending Goals to the Navigation Stack

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on the navigation stack of ros. I want to implement the following random video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFdlXCwbNh4
This video is showing exactly what i want to implement.
Kindly help me where can i find the source or tutorials so that i can understand and implement the same.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252220/sending-goals-to-the-navigation-stack/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-01-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vcanato](https://answers.ros.org/users/29088/vcanato/) on 2017-01-21**:
Which robot are you using for run the Goals to the navigation stack?, because my robot are not with move_base and now I need another. thank you

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-01-22**:
I am using the "diff-wheeled-robot" as mentioned in the book "mastering ROS for robotics". U may find the files and codes mentioned in the book from the following link. "https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros" If you need only the robot , you may direct get the "chapter_3_codes".

**Comment by [vcanato](https://answers.ros.org/users/29088/vcanato/) on 2017-01-22**:
works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial on [Sending goals to the navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) may get you started.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-01-17**:
Thank you for your reply.
I regret but i am not able to understand the prerequisite section of the tutorial. Is it necessary to use the two given links. Or can i simply run my own bot in gazebo and rviz and then check the cpp file?? And what exactly these two links are gonna perform??
Regards

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-17**:
The prerequisite is a robot or simulation running the navigation stack; the prerequisite links will show you how to start a simulation with navigation. If you already have your own robot or simulation running navigation, you can use that instead.

**Comment by [vcanato](https://answers.ros.org/users/29088/vcanato/) on 2017-01-17**:
I´m using the tutorial that you post
But on this step "rostopic .. _base/goal" I got no answer, so calling "rostopic list" I found running "move_base_simple/goal"
So I back to the "simple_navigation_goals.cpp" file and change only in line 11 "move_base" to "move_base_simple" but didn´t work.Help me?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-17**:
`move_base_simple/goal` is not an actionlib server, so sending goals to it probably won't work. If there's no `move_base/goal` topic, you may want to double-check that move base is running.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-01-18**:
Thank you @ahendrix . I have implemented the tutorial. I have used my bot to move a meter forward in my own loaded map.
Now i want to send the command to the bot which could make the bot to move in a any desired location (as shown in the video link). Can anyone help with with such code??
Regards

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-18**:
Sounds like you should extend the example with a list of goals, and loop over that list. For each goal, send the goal, wait for the robot to get to that point, and then repeat and send the next goal.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-01-18**:
but i want to make the user to send the goal on real time basis such that robot takes the input from user, moves to that location and so on.
setting multiple goals and pre-defining them in the program wont do the job
but i m not able to find any help from the net so far.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-18**:
The video you linked doesn't show any user interaction; the robot just appears to be following a pre-defined set of waypoints. If you want to command the robot manually, why not just send goals directly from rviz?

**Comment by [vcanato](https://answers.ros.org/users/29088/vcanato/) on 2017-01-18**:
Thank you for the answers ahendrix

Now I will see what do for move goal run

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-01-19**:
I am trying to modify the code to send multiple goals. So far, i am not able to successfully do that but trying.
If anyone has the similar code, or can help me in this code, kindly revert.
Thanks